# Is it possible to have MD5 & SHA-0 Collisions both at the same?

Tags: hash, md5, sha, hash-collision

I was studying about `MD5` collisions and found that collisions were also found in `SHA-0`.

Now, **Is it possible to have MD5 and SHA-0 colliosion in two Strings or Files at once?**

Here is an image showing a comparison table which i found while searching:
[image]

*Here, You can see in MD5 & SHA-0, on both possible collisions are found.*

Can anyone explain if it is possible to have both collisions at the same?

**I have got some example for MD5 Collisions. It would be better if someone can provide an example for MD5 & SHA-0 Collision both at the same?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collisions are possible in all hashes, it is a mathematical certainty. The reason it happens is called the [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), what it means is you only have `X` possible values for the hash to have, once you hash `X+1` items, you are guaranteed to have a collision because you must have used every hash value at least once making the `X+1` item you hash a guaranteed collision.

Now, apply this logic to MD5 and SHA1. Pretend you have a very long hash which is just the MD5 hash (`2^128` possible hashes) concatenated  on to the SHA1 hash (`2^160` possible hashes). You still have only have `2^128 * 2^160` possible hashes, once you hash `2^128 * 2^160 + 1` items you are guaranteed to have a item that had a collision in MD5 and a collision in SHA1 at the same time.

Would such a hash be easily found so that you could do a [second-preimage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack) attack so you could replace a existing hashed file with a 2nd one that had a matching hash? No, that attack would likely be unfeasible on the non-government level.

Comment: Nice explanation, also, do you have an example for the same?

Comment: @PraveshAgrawal Very unlikely. The chances to finding one via brute force are in the order of ``10^-87``. It is more likely to guess an AES-256 key by brute force.